# Standalone Runtime

Tags: runtime, frame, runtime-api, backend, standalone

I want to use Substrate Runtime in my application without consensus layer (outer node). I only want to create extrinsics in memory and pass them to runtime (or FRAME) of my custom pallets to proceed. How can I create instance of Runtime?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: to create a Runtime to be used inside an application without block authoring and consensus only runtime and state transition with database, without RPC and network activity. I pass extrinsics in memory to Runtime.

Comment: You already compile the runtime separately into a wasm target. Why not use that in your application? I have doubts if it will succeed without a host to call into the runtime so you maybe looking at implementing some kind of runtime interface similar to the outer node. Not sure how complex this would be though.